# Hdfs count command

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am using below command to assign a value, But for some reasons hdfs -count is disable. Is there a alternative way to get by tweaking the code

```
var=hdfs dfs -ls /hdfs_path/ | grep col=2020_03 | awk -F' ' '{system("hdfs dfs -count "$8)}' | awk -F' ' '{if ($3 != 0) print $4}' | awk -F'=' '{print $2}'|sort -nr | uniq | head -1
```

Basically i am need to find the latest month value that holds data in hdfs directory. For eg

```
hdfs_path/col=2020_03_21/data.part - this has no data
    hdfs_path/col=2020_03_20/data.part - this has data
    hdfs_path/col=2020_03_19/data.part - this has data
```

hence output should be `val = 2020_03_20`

Answer (score 0):

Create Hive External Table with 2 columns (data , date) and date as partition column. Run the hive query to get the date with data.

Select max(date) from table group by date  order by date having count(*) > 1

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the version of Hadoop you are using so I suppose it to be latest 3.x
Instead of -count command to check if the directory contains an non-empty file, you can use du -s command.
Your usual ls and grep then ->    |awk -F' ' '{system("hdfs dfs -du -s "$8)}' | awk -F' ' '{if ($2 != 0) print $3}'

Comment: Thanks fo that, Is it possible to do with du and count.

Comment: Nopes, I don't think so. Your query has two parts logically, First get the all the entries in the specified path, with specific value for date and the other one to check whether the entries are empty or not. The First part of getting all the entries can be done by ls command only, so, technically that doesn't have an alternative. The second part to check whether that directory has data or not, du -s or count can be used. As you mentioned in the question, only count command is disabled so du -s would lead you to the result..